# Generate a cloned Github wiki locally

Tags: git, github, markdown, wiki

I have several github repos that have their own wikis.

I can checkout out the wiki files as markdown by running

```
 git clone nameofproject.wiki
```

which is great.  However those files are just markdown - I'd like to be able to generate working linked html pages from them.  Is there a tool or system that makes it possible to do so?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/getting-started.html) or if you don't want to install something, try [Dingus](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus)? A [quick google search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=markdown+to+html&*) gave me a lot of suggestions.

Comment: @ht - I was fairly careful - I worded to ask if it was possible, rather than which is the best - does this still break the rules?

Comment: Yeah, still offtopic. A better network would have been http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ IIRC - but you got a good answer anyway, so just keep my notes for future reference `:)` It's allgood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub wikis are powered by [Gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum), an [open source](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/blob/master/LICENSE) Git-powered wiki that can be [installed locally](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/wiki/Installation). The exact mechanism for installing Gollum varies by operating system, but something like

```
gem install --user-install gollum
```

should do it on Linux or Mac systems with Ruby already installed.

Then you can simply run `gollum` from the wiki directory. This will run a web server running your wiki locally.